# Converting a list of nested dictionaries into a set inside of a dataframe

Tags: python, list, dataframe, dictionary, set

I've worked with python for quite some time, but for the life of me can't find a solution for converting a column in a dataframe that contains a list of nested dicts into a set containing only values.  This first line is an example of a row in my dataframe:

```
{'source': 'test', 'host': 'server1', 'event': 'metric', 'time': 1297361370, 'fields': {'_value': 0.0, 'metric_name': 'cloud_unit_used', 'enabled': 1, 'aid': 1283541, 'savedEvent': 0, 'accountGroupName': 'AG1', 'testId': 944111, 'testName': 'https://test.com - server1', 'testType': 'http-server', 'interval': 900, **'groups': [{'name': 'Asia Pacific', 'groupId': 11111, 'builtin': 0}, {'name': 'EMEA', 'groupId': 22222, 'builtin': 0}, {'name': 'Switzerland', 'groupId': 33333, 'builtin': 0}, {'name': 'Americas', 'groupId': 44444, 'builtin': 0}]**, 'server': '', 'test_sharing': 'Test Owner', 'url': 'https://server1', 'httpTimeLimit': 5.0, 'pageLoadTimeLimit': '', 'ftpTimeLimit': '', 'agentId': 55555.0, 'agentName': 'AGN1', 'agentType': 'Enterprise', 'countryId': 'GB'}}
```

The row contains a column labeled groups.  Groups is a list of nested dicts:

```
'groups': [{'name': 'Asia Pacific', 'groupId': 11111, 'builtin': 0}, {'name': 'EMEA', 'groupId': 22222, 'builtin': 0}, {'name': 'Switzerland', 'groupId': 33333, 'builtin': 0}, {'name': 'Americas', 'groupId': 44444, 'builtin': 0}]
```

I simply want to convert groups into a set containing only the name values in the nested dicts:

```
'groups': {'Asia Pacific','EMEA','Switzerland','Americas'}
```

Please note that the number of name values may vary. So in other rows, groups may contain 1 or more names.

Example of resultant row:

```
{'source': 'test', 'host': 'server1', 'event': 'metric', 'time': 1297361370, 'fields': {'_value': 0.0, 'metric_name': 'cloud_unit_used', 'enabled': 1, 'aid': 1283541, 'savedEvent': 0, 'accountGroupName': 'AG1', 'testId': 944111, 'testName': 'https://test.com - server1', 'testType': 'http-server', 'interval': 900, **'groups': {'Asia Pacific','EMEA','Switzerland','Americas'}**, 'server': '', 'test_sharing': 'Test Owner', 'url': 'https://server1', 'httpTimeLimit': 5.0, 'pageLoadTimeLimit': '', 'ftpTimeLimit': '', 'agentId': 55555.0, 'agentName': 'AGN1', 'agentType': 'Enterprise', 'countryId': 'GB'}}
```

Can someone please help me find the solution?  Very much appreciated all!

Comment: Do you want the set to only have the dictionaries' values? Or keys and values? Or just keys?

Comment: Provided a `list` of `dict` objects (`groups`), `s = {d['name'] for d in groups}` will extract all `dict` values associated with the key `'name'` from each `dict` into a `set` assigned to the variable `s`. Tested with the example provided and got expected output. Not 100% on how you'd best implement this within the context of a `df` update though - `df.apply()`?

Comment: Hi thank for responding Mushif... only the values.

Answer (score 1):

This is the general code for this:

For

```
groups= [{'name': 'Asia Pacific', 'groupId': 11111, 'builtin': 0}, {'name': 'EMEA', 'groupId': 22222, 'builtin': 0}, {'name': 'Switzerland', 'groupId': 33333, 'builtin': 0}, {'name': 'Americas', 'groupId': 44444, 'builtin': 0}]
```

The code is:

```
groups=set([i['name'] for i in groups])

print(groups)

{'Americas', 'Switzerland', 'EMEA', 'Asia Pacific'}
```

Please provide the df constructor if you need the code adjusted for the dataframe

Comment: Hi there archer.  I want to take a moment to thank you.  This is very helpful.  Python version is Anaconda 3.7 and I am using pandas from_dict to create the dataframe.  Hoping that is what you are looking for?

Comment: Still having issues making this work in a dataframe

Comment: Tried several different ways of trying to get the data into the dataframe, but have been unsuccessful so far:
for index, row in merged_df.iterrows():
    groups = row.groups
    groups=set([i['name'] for i in groups])
    merged_df.loc[index, 'groups'] = groups
 
 
for index, row in merged_df.iterrows():
    groups = row.groups
    regions=set([i['name'] for i in groups])
 
for index, row in merged_df.iterrows():
    groups = row.groups
    regions = set([i['name'] for i in groups])
    merged_df.loc[index,'regions'] = regions

Comment: Hi mojo Do you have your data in dataframe format?
The most effiecient way to construct your dataframe (given that you have your data already in a dictionary is the following:
`df=pd.DataFrame(your_dict)`
or you can add it manually like below:
`df=pd.DataFrame({'a':somedata, 'b':someotherdata, ...})` where 'a', 'b, etc will be your column names

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank you all for the help..  I was able to find a solution which worked:

```
    for row in merged_df.itertuples():
        merged_df.at[row.Index, 'labels'] = list(set([i['name'] for i in row.groups]))
    merged_df.drop('groups', inplace=True, axis=1)
```